# I am trying to plot a function I already defined, but the plot keeps showing up empty?

Tags: plotting, output

I defined g[x_] := 10 (x^7) e^(-2 x) and I am trying to plot it so I put in Plot[g[x], {x, 2, 6}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Filling -> Axis] and it keeps showing up empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct Mathematica syntax `e^(...)` is not the right syntax. It must be `Exp[...]`.

So the correct function would be: `g[x_] := 10*(x^7)*Exp[-2 x];`

Here is a good starting guide for math students if you are interested: [Fast introduction for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en///)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: It should be noted that simply `E^(...)` instead of `e^(...)` also works, as would `\[ExponentialE]^(...)` (where `\[ExponentialE]` looks nicer inside Mathematica, and can be entered by typing "Esc" ee "Esc" (so escape key, two e's, escape key)